# How to do CRUD operations on domain models using Casbah for MongoDb?

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

There is a tutorial on Casbah:

http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/current/tutorial.html

But I find it hard to follow the tutorial as I am still learning Scala.

All I wanted to find out how to do simple CRUD operations using Casbah to begin with
before I can go more advanced.

Given below domain models:

```
class Hotel (var name: String, var stars: Int, val address:  Address)

class Address(var street:String, var city: String, var postCode: String)



val address = new Address(street = "1234 st", city = "edmond", postCode = "1232234", country = "USA" )


  val hotel = new Hotel(name = "Super Nice", stars = 4, address =  address)

val address2 = new Address(street = "main st", city = "edmond", postCode = "1232234", country = "USA" )

val hotel2 = new Hotel(name = "Big Hotel", stars = 4, address =  address2)
```

Given above what Casbah code is to achieve these tasks?

(1) save both hotels in mongodb

(2) find all hotels that have stars equal to 4 or greater than 4. this should give me 
  a list over which I can iterate

(3) find a hotel by the name "Super Nice" and change its name to "Ultra Nice"

(4) get addresses of all hotels and change country to lower case and save in database

Comment: Did you manage to achive the tasks yet?

Comment: If you have done this, then it will be great if you could answer your own question. I'm sure there are a lot of newbies who would find such an example very helpful.

Comment: Some examples: https://github.com/talgendler/casbah

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see how to insert data: [Casbah wiki](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/current/tutorial.html#querying-with-casbah)

If you want to directly save case classes (without needing a MongoDBObject) in MongoDB you should have a look at Salat and SalatDao: [Salat presentation](http://repo.novus.com/salat-presentation)

In my opinion, the answers to question (2) - (4) can be found easily in the documentation of casbah and salat.